# Error while project analysis: SonarQube is unable to analyze file, IllegalStateException

Tags: java, sonarqube

One of our Java projects cannot be analyzed on SQ. The following error is thrown:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli) on project PPP: 
SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '<file-name>.java': IllegalStateException
```

The java file itself looks good. Nothing extraordinary in code.

We run SQ v5.6.3.

Do you know what causes the problem and how it can be solved?

Excerpt from the log:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli) on project <project-name>: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '<file-name>.java': IllegalStateException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli) on project <project-name>: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '<file-name>.java'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '<file-name>.java'
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:36)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.execute(RunnerBootstrapper.java:81)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '<file-name>.java'
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:93)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:67)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:119)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:113)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:87)
    at org.sonar.batch.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:57)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:234)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:274)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:165)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:152)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.execute(RunnerBootstrapper.java:78)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:159)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.BytecodeCompleter.complete(BytecodeCompleter.java:85)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.JavaSymbol.complete(JavaSymbol.java:111)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.JavaSymbol.isFlag(JavaSymbol.java:246)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.JavaSymbol.isEnum(JavaSymbol.java:197)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.MembersDifferOnlyByCapitalizationCheck.isVariableToExtract(MembersDifferOnlyByCapitalizationCheck.java:200)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.MembersDifferOnlyByCapitalizationCheck.extractMembers(MembersDifferOnlyByCapitalizationCheck.java:191)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.MembersDifferOnlyByCapitalizationCheck.retrieveMembers(MembersDifferOnlyByCapitalizationCheck.java:182)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.MembersDifferOnlyByCapitalizationCheck.visitNode(MembersDifferOnlyByCapitalizationCheck.java:56)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:95)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:78)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:64)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:123)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:84)
    ... 56 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

Comment: please provide at least the first few lines of the stacktrace, and the "caused by"

Comment: can you provide which version of the java analyzer your are running ?

Comment: Maven + org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1

Comment: I am talking about the version of the Sonar Java Analyzer that is installed on your SonarQube instance. Would you be able to share the code of the file causing the failure ? I suspect there is a name issue in that class that causes something to fail in the bytecode analysis

Comment: The newest one: version 4.2.1.6971

Comment: Then in order to figure out what is wrong we would definitily need the code (or a reproducer) that is causing the failure.

Comment: I could send it via email (privacy).

Comment: Please reach out to sonarqube@googlegroups.com (which is public) describing your problem and we'll see how you can send this file privately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the analysis is running with incompatible Java version of your code, check the version of Java in the classpath. For instance, in my case the analysis was running with Java 7 instead of Java 8.